# Class not found android.permission.INTERNET Ionic / Android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, gradle, android-permissions

When I try to launch my application on my smartphone (Samsung Galaxy J5) after the build, my application instantly crash with the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application android.permission.INTERNET: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.permission.INTERNET" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/fr.hardis.VBNantes-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/fr.hardis.VBNantes-1/lib/arm, /data/app/fr.hardis.VBNantes-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

I am using Ionic 5.2 with Angular.

I however tried to add this to my my config.xml:

```
    <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
    </edit-config>
```

Thank you for you help!

Comment: Why are you adding this here?? if you want your application to use internet go to your YourProject\platforms\android\app\src\mainAndroidManifest.xml file and add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: can you accept it as Answer if post it?

Comment: I have a similiar issue, but for `android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE`. did you ever solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android Permissions are added to AndroidMenifest.xml file inside your android platform folder.

If you want your application to use internet go to your

> YourProject\platforms\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

File and add blow Code:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: I have the permission in the Manifest file and it still doesn't work

Comment: what error are you getting? its better to open new Question with complete details and error logs.

Answer (score 0):

I solved something similar today.

The issue appears to be bad caching in the build system. You once had a plugin which required the `android.permission.INTERNET` permission then removed that plugin in some way that was mis-handled by the build system. It didn't clear whatever internal cache keeps track of included classes. Then when you added a plugin later which required that same permission, the build system believed it already had the required class included so it didn't add it in.

To solve this in my case; clean out all build artifacts (`cordova clean` in my case), remove all plugins, remove the platform itself (`cordova platform remove android` in my case), and then rebuild... add the plugins and platform and finally re-compile.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem than @Kae Verens but in my case i used an emulator to use the app.
So for those in my case you should (in addition to remove then add the platform) clean the emulator data (cache was stored and anything was working anymore). To do that i needed to do "wipe data" on the emulator from the device manager of android studio.
(i didn't do `cordova clean` and the above steps worked for me)